# uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for <https://www.facebook.com> to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I have the following code to get user data form facebook

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'the_app_code_here_but_i_didn't right_it_here',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
  <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
```

and here is the php code to pull the data using facebook.php class

```
$user_data = $this->facebook->getUser();

        if(!empty($user_data))
        {
            $uid = $this->facebook->getUser();
            $user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            if(!empty($user)) {



                print_r($user_data);
                die();
            }
            else
            {

                die("error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            die("error else");


        }
```

I get the **"error else"** and when i check firebug i have the following error **"uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for https://www.facebook.com to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger"**

I googled for it and there's no luck thought .. Is it aproblem with firefox as i'm using firefox 8 ?

Comment: Here id a discussion about this http://userscripts.org/topics/91081 may be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most up to date PHP + Javascript SDK sample is found here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/ - Facebook's backend requires oauth2.0 enabled on your app and it may be easier to just copy + paste a working app, then tweak it to your requirements.