# Facebook Connect error in Firefox 8.0

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-comments

I am using Facebook's Comment box and receive following error in Firefox 8.0 (No errors in other browsers).

> uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for
>   https://www.facebook.com to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger

Comment box works perfectly, I'm just curious if there's a way to fix this

Comment: I think this post has the same problem and was resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105778/uncaught-exception-error-permission-denied-for-https-www-facebook-com-to-g. This link also seems to be useful: codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=117050 .

Comment: Tuva, that covers the update to the PHP OAuth library. It has nothing to do with the javascript errors encountered in FF8 with the FB-provided Javascript SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding FB to an existing site and ran into the same issue. On IE, the same issue didn't happen but instead I got an error about a missing root. Moving my SDK call to below the fb-root div cleared both problems.

Hard to believe that would be the explanation for sites that previously worked with FB, though.