# JQuery AJAX GET - how to debug and check whats working

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I have the below JQuery.  Nothing happens and I have no idea how to debug this othr than using Firebug which is showing no errors.   How do I know where it is failing and if its even activating the script in the file?  This is being used in an iframe for a facebook app, could this this be an issue?  Any help much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shopkeeperID').submit(function(){
            var skID = $("#skID").val();
            showLoading();
        sendValue(skID);  
    });

});

function sendValue(str){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/var/www/web/shopkeeper/index.php",
          data: shopkeeper=+str,
          success: function(response) { 
          $('#response').html(response); 
            hideLoading();
            //refresh page
          }       
        });         
}       

    //show and hide loading icon
    function showLoading() {
      $("#loading").show();
    }

    function hideLoading() {
      $("#loading").hide();
    }
```

Comment: FROM JQUERY WEBSITE: "The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend using the console in **Firebug**. Among many other things, it's great for debugging jscripts. Shows you what kind of data is being passed and received and is good at identifying errors.

The problem seems to be what you're passing in **data**. You need a **key=>value** pair and it seems like you're only passing a value. E.g. `data : {'string' : myString}`.

Comment: Yes I am using firebug but am getting no errors and no clues as to whats going on.  This is for a facebook app that is in an Iframe, could that be an issue?  I thought what I had for data ws correct seing as IM using PHP and GET?

Comment: The iFrame should not be an issue. I use PHP and GET and I always have to pass a key and a value in my $.ajax. Does the console in firebug show that a GET is being executed? One thing you might try there is error-handling in your PHP page and echoing the error and then looking at the Response and Params in your GET call.

Comment: Ok I have changed the data as suggested. I have the firebug console open then select the submit function and nothing happens the firebug console apart from the following line:uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for <http://www.facebook.com> to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger.

Comment: Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105778/uncaught-exception-error-permission-denied-for-https-www-facebook-com-to-g

Comment: It looks like a Firefox issue.

Comment: Also check this out [seems to be exactly like what you are looking for]: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=117050

Comment: yes that does seem to be the problem and unfortunaltey the solution they state will not work as I cannot chnage the code in the containing facebook file.  :0(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the documentation more thoroughly.  You can set an error property that is a function that receives three parameters, the original request, a status message, and the error thrown.  Usually however the information here is pretty sparse.  So you should also look at the Firebug Net panel.  It will probably show that either you're getting a 404 on your request, or you will find that you're making a cross-domain request that isn't allowed, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to debug problems like this is to use an **HTTP Debugger**. If you are on Windows, [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a great tool. However, many browsers package these developer tools right into the product. Not to plug something vendor specific but Google Chrome has excellent developer tools built right into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what dnuttle has provided, you may also need to take a look at the ajax call you are making, usually I have to define a content type

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

But I'm not sure if this will help you out since this is php, most of the ajax calls I make are through asp.net so this comment might not have any weight.  Just ensure that all of the properties that you are setting up to make the ajax request are set to a proper value instead of the default.  btw the default value for contentType is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: Yes I assume the dafult is sufficient for a PHP script when using GET?

Comment: I wish I could say one way or the other, but without know for certain I am not going tell you one way is the right way or not. sorry.